# How to sign to agora RTC Wrapper

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, codesign, agora

I have a MacOS app in Unity and I use the agoraRTC Wrapper, how do I sign it?
Do you have AgoraRTC Wrapper version of AgoraTools/prep_codesign.sh and signcode.sh ?

I tried to change AgoraTools/prep_codesign.sh and signcode.sh to sign to agoraRTC Wrapper, but it did not work.
My app failed to initialize agora RTC Wrapper library.

Thank you.